# Branch.io prioritize social media links

Tags: branch, branch.io

1. it is easy to prioritize social media links in showShareSheet feature of Branch.io for Android,
   just use `.addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.TWITTER)`,
   but it add this apps in own (maybe alphabet) order, is it possible to avoid this order?
2. how prioritize this in IOS, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Branchster here -*

Currently, prioritization in the shareSheet method is not available.

However, we would recommend you create Branch Links through the Branch SDKs [getShortUrl](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-advanced-features#create-deep-link) method and use your own custom ShareSheet instead.